# Why is props.action not a function in my handleChange function?

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, material-ui

I'm relatively new to React and Material UI and  I'm trying to build a table with a list of names of candidates and a column to select these candidates and pass these values to another table. Howvever, I keep getting props.action is not a function in my handleChange function?

**My class's constructor**

```
class AssignExaminer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            candidate: dummyCandidate,
            checkedValues: []
        };
handleCheck(e, x) {
        this.setState(state => ({
            checkedValues: state.checkedValues.includes(x)
                ? state.checkedValues.filter(c => c !== x)
                : [...state.checkedValues, x]
        }));
    }
```

**My table**

```
<TableBody>
                                {(this.state.candidate).map((candidate) => (

                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            {candidate.name}
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            <Checkbox  onChange={e => this.handleCheck(e, candidate.name)}
                                                checked={this.state.checkedValues.includes(candidate.name)} />
                                        </TableCell>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        ))}
                            </TableBody>
```

**My checkbox class**

```
export default function CheckboxLabels(props) {

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.action(event);
  };

  return(
        <>
          <StyledCheckbox  checked={props.checked} onChange={handleChange}/>
            {props.name}
        </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prop you have passed down on to `CheckboxLabels` component is `onChange` and not `action` and hence you need to call `props.onChange`

```
export default function CheckboxLabels(props) {

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.onChange(event);
  };

  return(
        <>
          <StyledCheckbox  checked={props.checked} onChange={handleChange}/>
            {props.name}
        </>
  );
}
```